# Converting a while loop to a recursive function. (Cantor Pairing)

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function to unpair a number to the corresponding pair using [Cantor Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) function.

example : 0 -> (0,0), 1 -> (0,1), 2-> (1,0), 3 -> (0,2), 4 -> (1,1) ...

I coded it out using while loops as follow :

```
def unpair(n):
    current_sum = 0  #current  sum to generate the list
    num_counter = 0  #current num in list
    while current_sum <= n:
        c2 = current_sum   # right cantor num
        c1 = 0   # left cantor num
        while c2 >= 0 :
            if (num_counter == n):
                return c1,c2
            c2 -=1
            c1 +=1
            num_counter +=1 
        current_sum +=1
```

How to transform this to a recursive program?
I feel like the base case should be returning (0,0), but not sure about how to define the recursive steps while maintaing all the counters

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a double base case, as the transition from `(0, 0) -> (1, 0)` is different than the others

```
def unpair(n):
    if n == 0:
        return (0, 0)
    elif n == 1:             
        return (1, 0)
    else:
        x, y = unpair(n-1)
        if x == 0:
            return (y+1, 0)
        else:
            return (x-1, y+1)
```

That being said, I would use the equations from the [Inverting the Cantor Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function) for any actual application, especially one that may care about large numbers.

```
import math

def unpair(n):
    w = math.floor((math.sqrt(8*n + 1) -1) /2)
    t = (w*w + w)/2
    y = n - t
    x = w - y
    return (int(x), int(y))
```

Comment: thanks for you help, but the recursive solution you provided does not return the correct pair :(. I need it to be recursive because eventually I will implement using a functional programming language.

Comment: For what inputs?

Comment: output should be 0 -> (0,0), 1 -> (0,1), 2-> (1,0), 3 -> (0,2), 4 -> (1,1). but the function returns 2-> (2,0), 3 -> (0,1),4 -> (3,0)

Comment: Two points: Those aren't the outputs I get for those inputs.  Could you have copied the function wrong? Also, the outputs you're providing seem to be backwards.  The diagram on the wiki page presents cantor pairs as `(x, y)` but you have them as `(y, x)` Is this intentional?